# i am creating a function by lambda expression as below:-

Tags: python, lambda, wrapper

I am creating a function by lambda expression as below:

```
f=lambda x,y:True if x!='' else False if y!=''  else None
```

now when I use this function by passing a dictionary values in it

```
inv_d={'B2BNo':'','B2CNo':B2B-0038} 
print(f(inv_d['B2BNo'],d['B2CNo'])
```

it throws error:-

```
_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Do you mean to pass `f(inv_d['B2BNo'],inv_d['B2CNo'])`? Or tell us what is `d`. Also note that you missed a closing paranthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly discourage the temptation to write functions as on-line assignments of lambdas. Nested ternaries are also a huge code smell. It's easier to write and easier to debug if you write

```py
def f(x, y):
    if x: return True
    if y: return False
    return None
```

The following should work:

```
inv_d = {'B2BNo':'',
         'B2CNo':'B2B-0038'}
print(f(inv_d['B2BNo'], inv_d['B2BNo']))
```